# Inheritance - try to understand how it work

Tags: java, inheritance

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
    protected int _x;

    public A(){  
        _x = 1;  
    }
    public A(int x) {  
        _x = x;  
    }

    public void f(int x) {  
        _x += x;  
    }

    public String toString() {  
        return "" + _x;  
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public B() {  
        super(3);  
    }
    public B(int x) {
        super.f(x);
        f(x);
    }

    public void f(int x)
    {
        _x -= x;
        super.f(x);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    A[] arr = new A[3];
    arr[0] = new B();
    arr[1] = new A();
    arr[2] = new B(5);

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].f(2);
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand why after the first print the result is `3` and not `1`
At the beginning the `Class A`  empty constructor is called so `_x = 1` 
And than `f(int x) from class B` called so `_x = _x - 2` so `_x = -1` and after call `Super.f(x)` `_x = _x + x` ==> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element in your `arr` array is an object of type `A` which was initialized with the no argument constructor

```
arr[1] = new A();
...
public A(){  
    _x = 1;  
}
```

You call `f(2)` on that object. This will be the **`A#f(int)`** method (ie. the method `f()` in your `A` class)

```
public void f(int x) {  
    _x += x;  
}
```

you therefore add 2 to 1, ie. 3.

---

Seems you meant the first element. The first element is initialized with the no arg `B` constructor

```
arr[0] = new B();
...
public B() {  
    super(3);  
}
```

which invokes the `A` constructor

```
public A(int x) {  
    _x = x;  
}
```

setting `_x` to `3`. When you call `f(2)` on this object, it invokes the `f(int)` method in `B` because of polymorphism and late binding.

```
public void f(int x)
{
    _x -= x;
    super.f(x);
}
```

This will remove 2 to 3, ie. 1. But the `super.f(x)` will invoke `A`'s version of `f(int)` adding 2 back to `_x`, ie. the end result of `_x` is 3.

Comment: I mean the first element

Comment: I thought that because arr[0] = new B() s it's type of B

Comment: @user2976270 Absolutely, it is a `B` instance. You made its constructor call the super constructor and the method call the super method.

Comment: So why it goes into f inside A class and not B class ?

Comment: @user2976270 It goes through `B`'s `f()` method first, but then you have `super.f(x)` which calls `A`'s implementation.

Comment: Also i try to understand how the last iteration is 6, i try several times --> 5

Answer (score 0):

The first element is an instance of `B`. The default constructor is called which calls `super(3);`. `_x` will then be equal to 3. The first iteration of the loop will be `arr[0].f(2);` this will call the `f` method in `B`. This will decrement `_x` by 2, so 3-2=1. Then the super of `f` is called -> 1 + 2 = 3.

Comment: You mean The default constructor is called which calls super(2)

Comment: The default constructor in B calls super(3), does it not?